# Xslt filter by nodes and the group by subnodes?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
<Pizza Id="2" Type="P">
    <Flour Value="type A" Id="17" />
    <Tomato Value="cherry" Id="30" />
    <Cheese Value="swisscheese" Id="30" />
</Pizza>
<Pasta Id="3" Type="P">
    <Wheat Value="buckwheat" Id="16" />
    <Water Value="uuuuuuu" Id="14" />
</Pasta>
<Cake Id="27" Type="CP">
    <Flour Value="type B" Id="12" /> 
    <Chocolate Value="black" Id="28" />
    <Sugar Value="brown" Id="22" />
    <Milk  Value="fatfree" Id="15" />
</Cake>
<Pie Id="4" Type="P">
    <Flour Value="type A" Id="12"  /> 
    <Mushroom Value="xxxx" Id="15" />
</Pie>
<Pie Id="5" Type="X">
    <Steak Value="beef" Id="12"  /> 
    <Mushroom Value="xxxx" Id="15" />
</Pie>
</doc>
```

and I'm lookin for a transformation that provide an output like this:
      Flour

- type A used in:

  - Pizza (id="2")
  - Pie  (id="4")

  type B used in:

  - Cacke (id="27")

So first of all I would selects nodes of Type="P" or Type="CP" which is silly of course 
    
but I don't know how to handle the rest! 
I have sketched the following stylesheet but I don't know if I have to apply a group-by or iterate over subnodes. Or if I have to select directly Flour elements and check if parent is of Type='P' or 'CP' and do the rest;

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="doc">
    <html>
        <body>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
    <xsl:template match="doc/[@Type='P']|doc/[@Type='CP']">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <xsl:if test="Flour">

            </xsl:if> 
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Well, you know this is about *grouping* - so why don't you search for it? See http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html and many, many examples here on SO.

Comment: Yes I've tried to group-by with the following stylesheet:, but it doesn't give me the desiderated output.